# How to change amCharts bar chart balloon background color?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have to change balloon background color for a bar chart using JavaScript amCharts. Is there a way to change background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.Change the value fillColor : #000000 (to your desired color).

```
 "balloon": {
    "adjustBorderColor": true,
    "color": "#000000",
    "cornerRadius": 5,
    "fillColor": "#FFFFFF"
  }
```

Comment: scope.graphs=[
                {
                  "balloonText": "[[reporttime]]<br> [[storename]]: [[qtynumber]]<br> Index: [[QtyIndex]]",
                  "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                  "fillColorsField": "color1",
                  "id": "AmGraph-12",
                 "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                  "title": "amt",
                  "type": "column",
                  "showHandOnHover":true,
                  "valueField": "qty",
                   "labelText": "[[qtynumber]]",
                  "labelPosition": "right",
                  

                }]

Comment: Or can you share your skype id ?

Comment: Actually you can create a fiddle. So I can actually see what exactly is happening. I think your code is little messy and i am unable to understand what you are actually doing.

Comment: I have updated balloon setting which you have given in graphs method.

Comment: Please check  this  fiddle

Comment: Please check this.. added aqua color to baloons.
https://jsfiddle.net/sahilweb6/Lvaphsds/1/

Comment: Thanks,It's Working fine

Comment: Do You know how to show cursor on pie chart slices ?

Comment: Do You know how to make it has hand cursor ? check  the question which i have posted   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199839/how-to-show-hand-cursor-on-pie-charts-slices-using-amcharts

Comment: Ok giving you the solution there