# How to show hand cursor on pie charts slices using amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

How can we make the pie charts slice as a hyperlink or how to show at least hand cursor on slices.

check the code below. which i am using creating a pie chart using amcharts.

```
var initChart = function() {
        if (chart) chart.destroy();
        var config = scope.config || {};

        chart = AmCharts.makeChart(scope.chartid, {
          "type": "pie",
          "theme": "light",
          "marginTop": 10,
          "marginBottom":10,

          "allLabels": [{
            "text": scope.index,
            "color": "green",
            "bold" : true,
            "align": "center",
            "size": 20,
            "y": 190,



          }],
          "dataProvider":scope.chartdata,

          "titleField": "title",
          "valueField": "percent",

          "fontSize": 14,
          "labelRadius": 10,
          "radius": "25%",
          "innerRadius": "45%",
          "labelText": "[[title]]",
           "balloonText":"Sales Amt: $[[amt]]",
            "showHandOnHover":true,
          "export": {
            "enabled": true
          },


          "responsive": {
            "enabled": true,
            "addDefaultRules": false,
            "rules": [
              {
                "maxWidth": 400,
                "overrides": {
                  "fontSize": 6,
                  "labelRadius": 5,
                  "radius": "20%",
                  "innerRadius": "40%",
                  "allLabels": [{
                    "text": "1.02",
                    "color": "green",
                    "bold" : true,
                    "align": "center",
                    "size": 10,
                    "y": 210,



                  }]
                }
              }
            ]
          },

          "pullOutOnlyOne":true,
          "startEffect":"easeOutSine",
          "pullOutEffect":"easeOutSine",
         "listeners": [{
            "event": "clickSlice",
            "method": function(e) {

              var dp = e.dataItem.dataContext;

              scope.selectoption1=dp.title;

              if(scope.selectoption1!="OTHERS"){

                var object ={

                "title":scope.selectoption1,
                "id":dp.id

              }


                $rootScope.$emit('selecteddonutchartdep', object);

              }



              e.chart.validateData();
            }
          }]


        })

      };
```

Is there a way to show hand cursor on pie chart slice

Comment: So, which is it that you want? Please also add your code/partial code to the question so others can work with your code to solve the problem.

Comment: I want to show hand cursor on pie chart slices

Comment: And the code which you're working with now?

Comment: Please check below JsFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/ArunKumarUmma/L77p7jn5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of your problem and this is the correct way to do this ..
Below code and some css will do the magic..
AddClassname will add the appropriate class and effects that can make your graph a lot better and Css will add hand cursor only on the pie slice not on the overall area . Here is the fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/sahilweb6/wc8ezzn1/3/

**Additional Script**

```
"addClassNames": true,

  "innerRadius": "30%",
  "defs": {
    "filter": [{
      "id": "shadow",
      "width": "200%",
      "height": "200%",
      "feOffset": {
        "result": "offOut",
        "in": "SourceAlpha",
        "dx": 0,
        "dy": 0
      },
      "feGaussianBlur": {
        "result": "blurOut",
        "in": "offOut",
        "stdDeviation": 5
      },
      "feBlend": {
        "in": "SourceGraphic",
        "in2": "blurOut",
        "mode": "normal"
      }
    }]
  },
```

**CSS**

```
.amcharts-pie-slice {
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 #000;
}

.amcharts-pie-slice:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  filter: url(#shadow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in to the CSS

```
#chartdiv {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

It should give you what you want, but add the code to your question, so that anyone coming back here in the future can also see the full question and solution. There's no guarantee that your jsfiddle link will exist in the future.

Comment: How to show hand cursor on pie chart slice using amchart configuration.

Comment: Great. Could do with a little editing to put the first line within the code blocks, but it's better than it was originally.

Comment: Ok,Updated please check

Comment: Yep, that looks a lot better